# Unable to send html content with attachment using java mail api

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i want to send to send the html content along with an attachment. So how can it be sent in same mail ?

Could someone guide  me. Thanks

```
try {  

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  


            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,new InternetAddress("username@abc.com"));
             MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();  
            messageBodyPart1.setText(data, "text/html");
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();  
            String filename = "Data.xlsx";//change accordingly  
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);  
            messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));  
            messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);  
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);  
            message.setSubject("FOS Report");  
            message.setContent(multipart); 

    //send the message  
     Transport.send(message);  

     System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  

     }
 catch (MessagingException e) {
e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have two different types of contents, (binary and HTML in your case), you have to use Multipart for correct rendition.
You can learn about Multipart here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Multipart.html

On how to work with JavaMail with Multipart, a very nice tutorial here:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/javax.mail.Multipart

Please comment/ inbox if you require further assistance.

Comment: message.setContent(multipart.getBodyPart(i));

Comment: can i use get body part according to the index that i have provided at the time of adding body part